# Why can't I clone a repository from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

I'm new to git.

I don't know why I can't clone a repository anymore when I used a new laptop. In my previous laptop, I was able to clone it. Whenever I try to clone, it gives me the this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I have set my ssh-publick key in bitbucket. Still not working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you generate a new ssh key for your new laptop and upload that to Bitbucket? (I know you say you have one set, but you don’t say whether it’s for your old laptop or your new one.)

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is happening with your SSH connection, execute the "git clone" command the following way:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ssh://REPO-URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clone it using HTTPS. Toggle the link here:

[image]